# How to list out latitude and longitude points located between two degrees

Tags: php, web-services, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-search-api

I have a database with list of latitude and longitude points i want to search.

Now, how can i list the latitude and long points which are situated in **between 0 and 45** degrees or in range of **15 to 30 degrees** . Is there any method or api.

The post values are **lat,long and degreeslowerlimit and degreesupperlimit**.

Please help me to achieve this

Comment: Actually i am implementing this task as a back end service but not for any site.So i have to code the logic.  At the same time looking at the html you provided , i got an idea. I will let you know if it works. Thank you so much for the valuable response

Comment: The list you're asking for is infinite! Try re-thinking your question.

Comment: No it cannot be infinite. Because i already have 162 values in my db. I will show only those points on my map(iphone)

Comment: The number of points between two points are infinite.

Comment: Well thanks but i am not familiar with those points(what you are saying as infinite). That is what the reason i said it cannot be infinite. Can you suggest me how can i achieve this by other means. Any methods or steps to be followed.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your database is MySQL

```
$minLat = $_POST[degreeslowerlimit);//depending on your parameters
$maxLat = $_POST[degreeslowerlimit) ;

$STH = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE `latitude` BETWEEN :minLat AND :maxLat')
$STH->bindParam(':minLat', $minLat);
$STH->bindParam(':maxLat', $maxLat);

$STH->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

http://transition.fcc.gov/mb/audio/bickel/DDDMMSS-decimal.html

Check the Javascript. It is straightforward.